# Start-BITSTransfer with network share as destination

Tags: powershell, bits

I'm using `Start-BITSTransfer` to download a file from the internet and place it in a network location.  The location is similar to `\\computername\c$\folder` which the cmdlet says it can't find and that it doesn't exist.

To get `Test-Path` to pass successfully you have to add the filesystem provider to the location like this: `filesystem::\\computername\c$\folder`.  The rub is that `Start-BITSTransfer` doesn't like destinations with the filesystem provider declared and errors with "The path is not of a legal form".

The problem is further compounded by the inability to use `Invoke-Command` and run the code in a remote shell on the destination server.  `Start-BITSTransfer` blocks this usage.

What's the solution to using `Start-BITSTransfer` with a network location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this I had to change my location from the CMSite provider drive `CMSite:\` to a filesystem provider drive `cd c:` and then initiate the BITS Transfer.  Apparently the CMSite provider doesn't inherit this operation.